# java method . 'computer' method never running after 'bonegame' method

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to create a game with a player versus a CPU. I've finished the player part, but the CPU method named `computer` will not run. In theory the `computer` method should run after the players turn is done.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // acknowledgements
    System.out.print("welcome to the Bone game ---  ");
    System.out.println("Created by the indigenous Blackfoot tribe");
  System.out.println("=======================================================================");

    int playerScore = bonegame(10);
    System.out.println("Player score: " + playerScore);
    int computerScore = computer(10);
    System.out.println("Computer score: " + computerScore);
    if (playerScore > computerScore) {
      System.out.println("Player wins!");
    } else if (computerScore > playerScore) {
      System.out.println("Computer wins!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    }
    bonegame(10);
    score1();
  }

  //bone game method
  public static int bonegame(int round){
    // variables
    
    Random random = new Random();
    //int cir = 3,dia = 4,tri = 2,lin = 1,che = 1,blanc = 0;
    int cir = random.nextInt(2);
    int dia = random.nextInt(2);
    int tri = random.nextInt(2);
    int lin = random.nextInt(2);
    int che = random.nextInt(2);
    //int comp = computer(cpu);
  
    String c = "circle";
    String bl = "blank";
    String d = "diamond";
    String t = "triangle";
    String l = "line";
    String check = "checkered";
    
    round = 10;
    int reroll = 0;
    int score = 0;
    while (round >= 0 || score <= 20){
      //System.out.println(reroll);
      System.out.println("round: "+ round);
      //System.out.println("your score: " + score);
      // System.out.println("computer score: "+ cpu);
      System.out.println("--------------------------");
      if(cir ==1){
        score += 3;
        System.out.println(c);
      }
      if(dia ==1){
        score += 4;
        System.out.println(d);
      }
      if(tri ==1){
        score += 2;
        System.out.println(t);
      }
      if(lin ==1){
        score += 1;
        System.out.println(l);
      }
      if(che ==1){
        score += 1;
        System.out.println(check);
      }
      //blanks
      if(cir ==0){
        System.out.println(bl);
      }
      if(dia ==0){
        System.out.println(bl);
      }
      if(tri ==0){
        System.out.println(bl);
      }
      if(lin ==0){
        System.out.println(bl);
      }
      if(che ==0){
        System.out.println(bl);
      }
      if (reroll == 3) {
        System.out.println("You have used all your rerolls.");
        break;
      }
      if (score >= 20){
        System.out.println("You win:"+ score);
        break;
      }
      System.out.print("current score: ");
      System.out.println(score);
      System.out.println("-----------------");
      //accept y or n
      Scanner play = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("To reroll type y ---- to continue type n");
      String move = play.nextLine();
      if (move.equals("y")){
        reroll ++;
        score = 0;
        cir = random.nextInt(2);
        dia = random.nextInt(2);
        tri = random.nextInt(2);
        lin = random.nextInt(2);
        che = random.nextInt(2);
        round = 10;
      }
      else {
        round --;
      }
    }
    return score;
  }

  //score
  public static int score1() {
    int scored = bonegame(10);
    System.out.println("Player score: " + scored);
    System.out.println(" ");
    return scored;
  }

  // Computer turn
  public static int computer(int cpu){
    Random random1 = new Random();
    int cir = random1.nextInt(2);
    int dia = random1.nextInt(2);
    int tri = random1.nextInt(2);
    int lin = random1.nextInt(2);
    int che = random1.nextInt(2);
    int ron = bonegame(10);
    String c = "circle";
    String bl = "blank";
    String d = "diamond";
    String t = "triangle";
    String l = "line";
    String check = "checkered";

    while (ron >= 0 || cpu <= 20){
      System.out.println("--------------------------");
      if(cir ==1){
        cpu += 3;
        System.out.println(c);
      }
      if(dia ==1){
        cpu += 4;
        System.out.println(d);
      }
      if(tri ==1){
        cpu += 2;
        System.out.println(t);
      }
      if(lin ==1){
        cpu += 1;
        System.out.println(l);
      }
      if(che ==1){
        cpu += 1;
        System.out.println(check);
      }
      //blanks
      if(cir ==0){
        System.out.println(bl);
      }
      if(dia ==0){
        System.out.println(bl);
      }
      if(tri ==0){
        System.out.println(bl);
      }
      if(lin ==0){
        System.out.println(bl);
      }
      if(che ==0){
        System.out.println(bl);
      }
      if (cpu >= 20){
        System.out.println("You lost:"+ cpu);
        break;
      }
      System.out.print("current CPU score: ");
      System.out.println(cpu);
      System.out.println("-----------------");
    }
    return cpu;
  }
}
```

After `bonegame` method has allowed the user one round, the next round will be the CPU's until one reaches 20 points.

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: You wrote in your question: _after 'bonegame' method has allowed the user one round, the next round will be the CPU's until one reaches 20 points._ That's not how your code works. It keeps giving the player another turn and another turn until she has exhausted all her rounds or her score has reached 20 points. Then method `computer` is [definitely] executed. Why do you think method `computer` does not run?

Comment: @abra I was not aware of it running afterwards. So how could I fix ‘bone game’ method to stop after one round? To allow for the CPU

Answer (score 0):

In order for the player and the computer to take turns, you need to execute a single turn for the player, followed by a single turn for the computer and you need to repeat that in a loop until either all the rounds are exhausted or someone wins.

The below code is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Note that you only need to create a `Random` object and a `Scanner` object only once – and not each time you need to generate a random number or get input from the user.

I suggest that you run the code with a debugger as that may help you better understand how the code works.

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoneGame {
    private static final int POINTS_BLANK = 0;
    private static final int POINTS_CHECKERED = 1;
    private static final int POINTS_CIRCLE = 3;
    private static final int POINTS_DIAMOND = 4;
    private static final int POINTS_LINE = 1;
    private static final int POINTS_TRIANGLE = 2;
    private static final int REROLLS = 3;
    private static final int ROUNDS = 10;
    private static final int WINNER = 20;

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    private static final Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static final String BLANK = "blank";
    private static final String CHECKERED = "checkered";
    private static final String CIRCLE = "circle";
    private static final String DIAMOND = "diamond";
    private static final String LINE = "line";
    private static final String TRIANGLE = "triangle";

    private static int rerolls;

    private static int turn() {
        int checkered = RANDOM.nextInt(2);
        int circle = RANDOM.nextInt(2);
        int diamond = RANDOM.nextInt(2);
        int line = RANDOM.nextInt(2);
        int triangle = RANDOM.nextInt(2);
        int score = 0;
        if (checkered > 0) {
            System.out.println(CHECKERED);
            score += POINTS_CHECKERED;
        }
        if (circle > 0) {
            System.out.println(CIRCLE);
            score += POINTS_CIRCLE;
        }
        if (diamond > 0) {
            System.out.println(DIAMOND);
            score += POINTS_DIAMOND;
        }
        if (line > 0) {
            System.out.println(LINE);
            score += POINTS_LINE;
        }
        if (triangle > 0) {
            System.out.println(TRIANGLE);
            score += POINTS_TRIANGLE;
        }
        if (score == POINTS_BLANK) {
            System.out.println(BLANK);
        }
        return score;
    }

    private static int turnComputer() {
        System.out.println("====================================================================");
        System.out.println("Computer turn...");
        return turn();
    }

    private static int turnPlayer() {
        System.out.println("====================================================================");
        System.out.println("Player turn...");
        int score = turn();
        System.out.println("You scored: " + score);
        if (rerolls < REROLLS) {
            System.out.print("Roll again? [Y/N]: ");
            String choice = STDIN.nextLine();
            if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)) {
                rerolls++;
                score = turn();
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You have no more rerolls.");
        }
        return score;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int scoreComputer = 0;
        int scorePlayer = 0;
        int round = 1;
        while (round <= ROUNDS) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("====================================================================");
            System.out.printf("Round %2d:%n", round);
            scorePlayer += turnPlayer();
            System.out.println("Your current score: " + scorePlayer);
            if (scorePlayer >= WINNER) {
                System.out.println("You win!");
                break;
            }
            scoreComputer += turnComputer();
            System.out.println("Computer current score: " + scoreComputer);
            if (scoreComputer >= WINNER) {
                System.out.println("Computer won.");
                break;
            }
            round++;
        }
        if (round > ROUNDS) {
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        }
    }
}
```

Output from a sample run...

```
====================================================================
Round  1:
====================================================================
Player turn...
diamond
triangle
You scored: 6
Roll again? [Y/N]: N
Your current score: 6
====================================================================
Computer turn...
checkered
circle
line
triangle
Computer current score: 7

====================================================================
Round  2:
====================================================================
Player turn...
checkered
diamond
line
You scored: 6
Roll again? [Y/N]: n
Your current score: 12
====================================================================
Computer turn...
checkered
circle
diamond
Computer current score: 15

====================================================================
Round  3:
====================================================================
Player turn...
circle
diamond
You scored: 7
Roll again? [Y/N]: y
checkered
triangle
Your current score: 15
====================================================================
Computer turn...
diamond
line
Computer current score: 20
Computer won.
```